# How can I put API data to angular chart?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to put spotify API to a chart and here is my components for chart:

API from spotify:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(map((params) => params["id"])).subscribe((id) => {
      this.userService.getAudioFeature(id).subscribe((trackFeature) => {
        this.trackFeature = trackFeature;
        console.log(this.trackFeature);
      });
    });
}
```

Chart example:

```
  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  barChartLabels: Label[] = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Kiwifruit",
    "Blueberry",
    "Orange",
    "Grapes",
  ];
  barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartPlugins = [];

  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [this.trackFeature.danceability, 37, 60, 70, 46, 33], label: "Audio Features" },
  ];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [example](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/BarChart)

Data must be in the following format...

```
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
  ];
```

Updated answer:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  trackFeature:any;

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [10,20,30,40,50], label: 'Series A' }
  ];

   constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    //push data from api
    this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params["id"])).subscribe(id => {
      this.userService.getAudioFeature(id).subscribe(trackFeature => {
        this.trackFeature = trackFeature;
        //if data received then push into your chart
        if (this.trackFeature != null) {
          this.barChartData = [
            {
              data: [this.trackFeature.danceability, this.trackFeature.energy],
              label: "Series A"
            }
          ];
        }
      });
    });

  } //end ngOnInit
}
```

Live example [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template)

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Comment: How can I get data from the API in my ngOnInit?

Comment: Is this.trackFeature a global variable ?

Comment: No I didn't declare it global variable. How to do it?

Comment: Declare this variable where your component class start. like: export class YourComponent {  
  trackFeature:number;  
}

Comment: i declare it like this: ```trackFeature: [];```

Comment: Did you see my photo? I want to grab those data from the API in ngOnInit to my chart data

Comment: You can also declare it like as  trackFeature:number[]=[10,20,30,40,50];

Comment: Can you tell which data you want to keep inside the trackFeature array?

Comment: So when I ```console.log(this.trackFeature);``` It will show me the data like in the photo and I want to get ```danceability, energy```  and bind them into chart data

Comment: I got this error ```Property 'danceability' does not exist on type '[]'.```

Comment: please change type of `trackFeature:[]` to `trackFeature: any`

Comment: Getting this error in chrome console ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'danceability' of undefined```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216691/discussion-between-mahipal-choudhary-and-nathannewyen).